# question about functions in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a php file with two function

```
<?php 

function first () {
//in real case more conditions
echo "first";
return true;
}

function second () {
//in real case more conditions
echo "second";
return true;
}

first();
second();

?>
```

and in an ajax file

```
function(data) {
                if (data == "first") {
                    $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('something');
                    });
                } 
                else if (data == "second") {
                    $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('Something else');
                    });
                }
```

the problem is because the php devolve firstsecond and i need to check in a individual mode - first and second. If i make return first; how i can check in data if the return is correct? data==first not working

thanks

Comment: I would recommend sending back a JSON encoded string. It would be parsed as an object in JavaScript. Take a look at http://php.net/JSON

Comment: ok, suppose that i send back a string. i check data==$string ?? or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd want something more along these lines:

```
function first() {
    if (some condition ...) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function second() {
   if (some other condition...) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$data = array();

$data['first'] = first();
$data['second']= second();

echo json_encode($data);
```

Then in your Javascript code:

```
if (data.first) {
   ... first occurred
}
if (data.second) {
   ... second occured;
}
```

Must better to return actual Javascript data structures via JSON encoding, than a string. This way you can pass in other data elements. For instance, if `first()` was doing a database lookup and something blew up, you can return a 'false' along with an error message indicating why the request failed.

Comment: this data.validateName check if the return is true correct? and to check if the return is false? It is correct !data.validateName ?

Comment: It'd be whatever names you assign in PHP. JSON is simply there to translate from the native PHP datatypes to the equivalent Javascript ones.